# Why does karma fail with "PhantomJS ... ERROR ... __zone_symbol__currentTask"

Tags: angular, promise, phantomjs, karma-runner, angular-cli

Suddenly (w/ no code changes) karma unit tests in PhantomJS 2.1.1 for Angular 4.0.0 angular-cli 1.0.0 project fail with fairly opaque error:

```
[INFO] PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
[INFO]   {
[INFO]     "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[INFO]       "type": "microTask",
[INFO]       "state": "notScheduled",
[INFO]       "source": "Promise.then",
[INFO]       "zone": "<root>",
[INFO]       "cancelFn": null,
[INFO]       "runCount": 0
[INFO]     }
[INFO]   }
[INFO] 
[INFO] PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
[INFO]   {
[INFO]     "__zone_symbol__currentTask": {
[INFO]       "type": "microTask",
[INFO]       "state": "notScheduled",
[INFO]       "source": "Promise.then",
[INFO]       "zone": "<root>",
[INFO]       "cancelFn": null,
[INFO]       "runCount": 0
[INFO]     }
[INFO]   }
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO]
```

Using Node v6.9.1, npm 3.10.8.

Contents of package.json:

```
{
  "name": "f2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Geneva UI - Fast and Furious",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5",
    "angular-messages": "1.6.2",
    "angular-resource": "~1.5",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "~2.5",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.3.1",
    "angular-touch": "~1.5",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.5",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.5",
    "angular-animate": "~1.5",
    "angular-translate": "~2.7",
    "angular-highlightjs": "~0.7.1",
    "angular-clipboard": "1.5.0",
    "highlight.js": "~9.10.0",
    "CSV-JS": "~1.2",
    "uigrid": "~3.0",
    "highcharts": "5.0.8",
    "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.10",
    "moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020": "0.4.0",
    "bootstrap-colorpicker": "~2.3",
    "ng-bootstrap-tree": "1.0.0",
    "ng-circle-progress": "0.9.6",
    "jstz": "1.0.9",
    "highcharts-export-csv": "1.4.6",
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.4",
    "@types/angular": "1.6.5",
    "@types/angular-resource": "1.5.8",
    "@types/angular-ui-bootstrap": "0.13.40",
    "@types/angular-ui-router": "1.1.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.52",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.40",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.63",
    "add-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "angular2-busy": "^2.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.8.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "4.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "^6.0.1",
    "gulp-rimraf": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-systemjs-builder": "0.15.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.1.3",
    "gulp-typings": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.3",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.3",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "~1.12.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "ng-bootstrap": "1.6.3",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-slimscroll": "^2.0.1",
    "ng2-tooltip": "0.0.7",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.8.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "~8.0.2",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^7.1.0",
    "primeng": "4.1.2",
    "protractor": "~5.2.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.4",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslint": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "3.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.5.2"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

It's an Angular project and the unit tests do use Promise, but they've never had this problem before.

Some of these versions are un-pinned, so there may be recent version changes. I'm looking for and possibly expecting to find a culprit library.

Comment: Hmm, I see karma-webpack is now resolving to 2.0.9. Previously this was working with 2.0.6. If I pin to that version, my unit tests work and pass. So it looks like it's an issue correlated with karma-webpack@2.0.9. Not sure if it's a bug there or my own bug is now revealed by karma-webpack, but if the latter the error message is pretty cryptic.

Comment: Submitted a bug https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack/issues/290